# Bulk updating reference numbers, returning 0 records from code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written a piece of SQL that is to match old reference numbers with new ones, and overwrite them.

The context for this is that we received over 3000 invoices from a supplier with the incorrect reference number. They have supplied the correct ones to me in an Excel file.

I've created a new table in our DB and loaded the data of the new references. I am then running the below.

I ran this first through a UAT environment with test data and the code did exactly what I wanted. But when I run the below, I keep getting a return of 0.

Below is the code I'm using

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Refr1 = b.RefNEW
FROM ESB_EDI_HEADERS AS a
INNER JOIN Musgrave_EDI AS b ON a.Refr1 = b.RefOLD
```

Context:

`ESB_EDI_HEADERS` table contains all our invoices. This is where we received incorrect reference numbers on invoices.

`Musgrave_EDI` is a new table I made, where I imported data from an Excel file.

I think there might be an issue with the data I imported as when I run the below I get no responses back.

```
SELECT Refr1
FROM ESB_EDI_Headers
INTERSECT
SELECT RefOLD 
FROM Musgrave_EDI
```

Here I am trying to see where the existing references match, and yet I get no results here either.

Appreciate any guidance or help on this, I feel it is a data issue, although not sure how I can share the data in question on this platform.

Below is some example data from the tables

**Musgrave_EDI**
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM Musgrave_EDI

```
RefOLD      RefNEW
C2300008338 0
C2300008339 0
C2300008340 0
C2300027652 0
C2300027653 0
C2300027656 0
C2300005878 7439
C2300004652 8172
C2300004653 8752
C2300004654 9385
```

**ESB_EDI_HEADERS**
    SELECT TOP 10 Sitecode,
                  Supplier,
                  TrDate,
                  Refr1,
                  Refr2
    FROM ESB_EDI_HEaders
    WHERE DateImported >='2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'

```
Sitecode    Supplier    TrDate          Refr1       Refr2
5017    000011  2016-04-28 00:00:00.000 8228378422  E02591436
5057    000011  2016-04-28 00:00:00.000             E02591454
5012    000011  2016-04-25 00:00:00.000 78316997    E02591989
5012    000011  2016-04-27 00:00:00.000 78344448    E02591990
5012    000011  2016-04-29 00:00:00.000 78367685    E02591991
5011    000011  2016-04-25 00:00:00.000 78314138    E02591992
5011    000011  2016-04-28 00:00:00.000 78352647    E02591993
5011    000011  2016-04-30 00:00:00.000 78376810    E02591994
5013    000011  2016-04-25 00:00:00.000 78316973    E02592104
5013    000011  2016-04-27 00:00:00.000 78343940    E02592105
```

Comment: Can you try this. UPDATE ESB_EDI_HEADERS
SET Refr1 = b.RefNEW
FROM Musgrave_EDI AS b
WHERE
 ESB_EDI_HEADERS.Refr1 = b.RefOLD

Comment: Tried this and also received a 0 records returned

Comment: can you add some value for 2 tables?

Comment: Added to the Original Post for formatting purposes

Comment: There is no relationship between tables?

Comment: ESB_EDI_Headers.Refr1 is equal to Musgrave.EDI.RefOLD

Comment: These colums are not matching. Check your values

Answer (score 1):

So got this all sorted. Turns out the details I received from an end user was incorrect, so it was actually Refr2 that needed to be in the join.

After this I started getting records back. Was some additional issues, but that was caused due to blanks provided by the vendor.

So I solved this issue using the code below

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE ESB_EDI_HEADERS 
SET Refr2 = b.Refer2
FROM Musgrave_EDI AS b 
WHERE Refr2 =CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),b.Record)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does a.Refr1 and b.RefOLD have the same data type? The problem might be because the column you are joining don't match each other.

Comment: Initially there was a datatype issue with the RefOLD (and RefNEW) being a float and having a decimal. I've resolved that and all datatypes are now nVARCHAR

Comment: As for your example and since you didn't have any results after the intercept between the 2 tables that means that  RefOLD doesn't have any reference to Refr1. That is why you are having 0 results.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am thinking. I've tried loading the data in multiple ways from Excel,csv etc. Can't seem to figure out what the issue is, I've checked for white spaces and the likes